# How to make boost run in release mode

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, boost, g++

I have some code that I usually run on my work machine, I have built and run it at home but the runtime is significantly slower. Both machines have i7 processors, the code is single core and both have enough memory (work - 16Gb home 8Gb but using top only ~2Gb needed). The only thing I can think of is boost is running in debug mode on my home build.

I have explicitly set the active mode to release in eclipse, I have compiled with the -O3 flag. I am just out of ideas now. Am I missing something else, or by doing this am I ensuring that boost is not running in debug mode?

Thanks

Comment: Most of the boost library is contained in header files, so if you do a 'clean' you'll be rebuilding everything from scratch including boost (unless you're using their filesystem library or a few others as .so).  So if you're telling g++ to build in release mode, then that's what it's doing and your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Practically all of Boost is implemented in header files, so it will be compiled with the same optimizations as the project using it.  I suspect that Boost is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, In eclipse run configurations you must also change the App location from `Debug/app` to `Release/App`.

Not sure whether to close this as too localized or maybe it well help someone, perhaps a moderator can decide.

Comment: you might want to add an ``eclipse`` tag :)